# \stepcounter does not work in \item optional argument

Tags: lists, counters

I need a simple enumerate list with a custom label but I can't use the `enumitem` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{1}
\newcommand{\mycounter}{\stepcounter\arabic{mycounter})}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\mycounter] test
\item[\mycounter] test
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Which throws an error. If I remove `\stepcounter` the error goes away but the number does not increase. Another requirement (other than not using `enumitem`) is that this should not affect the entire enumerate list but only some items to be chosen manually).

To clarify, I can't use `enumitem` nor any other package.

Comment: `\stepcounter{}` needs an argument :)

Comment: Also, welcome to TeX.SX! `:)`

Comment: Please forgive me for the super noob question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{1}
\newcommand{\mycounter}{\stepcounter{mycounter}\arabic{mycounter}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[\mycounter] test
\item[\mycounter] test
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```